# Идентификатор сессии в cookie, есть такой?

Tags: cookie

Подскажите, пожалуйста, я вообще ни разу не frontend но задача очень плотно пересекается с cookie. Есть ли какой-то атрибут, по умолчанию который при каждом заходе на сайт вешает на пользователя какой-то уникальный идентификатор, который при каждом закрытии и открытии браузера обновляется. И если есть, как он называется и где его можно найти?

Comment: По умолчанию — нету, каждый разработчик сайта делает как сам хочет (или не делает, если не хочет или законы запрещают)

Comment: andreymal  может посоветуете алгоритм генерации подобного? Чтобы не изобретать велосипед

Comment: @ДядяФёдор, на каком языке программирования вам нужен код?

Comment: @ДядяФёдор как правило, в любом более-менее популярном веб-фреймворке уже встроен какой-нибудь механизм сессий, читайте соответствующую документацию

Comment: на java script )